# Given $|\int f(\zeta)\,d\zeta-1|<\epsilon$, what can we say about $\int|f(\zeta)|\,d|\zeta|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-integration, gaussian-integral

Consider the following unbounded curve in $\Bbb C$
$$
\Gamma=\{x+ih(x),\;\;x\in\Bbb R\}
$$
where $h\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a bounded $\mathscr C^1$ real function, such that $h'(x)\to0$ as $|x|\to\infty$; hence $\Gamma$ is roughly a perturbation of $\Bbb R$ inside $\Bbb C$.

My case deals with the gaussian kernel
$$
K_t(\zeta,z):=\frac{1}{t\sqrt \pi}e^{-\frac{(\zeta-z)^2}{t^2}}
$$
where $t>0$ and $z$ is a fixed point in $\Gamma$ and $\zeta\in\widetilde\Gamma:=\{\zeta\in\Gamma\;:\;\Re(\zeta-z)\le\eta\}$ for some $\eta\ge0$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $t_0>0$ such that
$$
\left|\int_{\widetilde\Gamma}K_t(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta-1\right|<\epsilon
$$
for all $0<t<t_0$.
This tells us that the complex number
$$
w:=\int_{\widetilde\Gamma}K_t(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta
$$
stays in a $\epsilon$-ball around $1$. Fine, so far.

I wonder: what can we say about
$$
\int_{\widetilde\Gamma}|K_t(\zeta,z)|\,d|\zeta|\;\;?
$$
Clearly one gets
$$
\epsilon
>\left|\int_{\widetilde\Gamma}K_t(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta-1\right|
\ge 1-
\left|\int_{\widetilde\Gamma}K_t(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta\right|
\ge 1-\int_{\widetilde\Gamma}|K_t(\zeta,z)|\,d|\zeta|
$$
from which
$$
\int_{\widetilde\Gamma}|K_t(\zeta,z)|\,d|\zeta|>1-\epsilon\;.
$$
Would it be possible to prove that
$$
\int_{\widetilde\Gamma}|K_t(\zeta,z)|\,d|\zeta|<1+\epsilon\;?
$$

Comment: In the general case there is no bound in the other direction. $\int|f(\zeta)|\,d|\zeta|$ can be arbitrarily large while $\int f(\zeta)\,d\zeta$ is equal to one.

Comment: $\epsilon \gt \left|\int_{\widetilde\Gamma}K_t(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta-1\right|
\ge | | \int_{\widetilde\Gamma}K_t(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta| - |1| |$. So, $\epsilon \gt | \int_{\widetilde\Gamma}K_t(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta| - 1 \Rightarrow 1+\epsilon \gt  | \int_{\widetilde\Gamma}K_t(\zeta,z)\,d\zeta| $. Your desired inequality.

Comment: @user264745: No, the desired inequality is $1+\epsilon\ > \int_{\widetilde\Gamma}|K_t(\zeta,z)|\,d|\zeta|$.

Comment: @MartinR Opps... I’m sorry.